# shadowbox.js bug with bxSlider in Firefox 26.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider, shadowbox

I've have a mysteric "problem" (The X- Files ^^) with shadowbox.js and bxSlider in Firefox 26.0

Bug description:
After you click on a small image to open this image as "preview" in shadowbox.js, thumbnails from bxSlider disappear completely - but if you move a mouse on once of this thumbnails or click with your right mouse, move browser etc. they are back ^^

Demo: http://stark-immo.com/immo_details.php?id=249

[image: bug demo screen]

Comment: It's work fine with me. Do you receive any error?

Comment: nope, no error! In Safari and Chrome everything is ok - but not in Firefox. Same problem on Windows and Firefox 26.0